# Is Portugal open to travel from Brazil and vice versa, by plane? Covid problems?

Tags: air-travel, brazil, portugal

Is Portugal open to travel from Brazil by plane?

Comment: Are you asking about travelling from Portugal to Brazil or from Brazil to Portugal? Have you checked the website from the Brazilian or Portuguese ministry for foreign affairs?

Comment: From brasil to portugal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Portugal to Brazil:
It is open at this moment. You need to have a PCR test and fill out the form https://formulario.anvisa.gov.br/index.php/39183?lang=pt-BR

From Brazil to Portugal: You should have a TRAg, PCR test or Covid Certificate. Also, you should be an EU Citizen or having a Portuguese Residence. Finally, you should fill out two forms.

Source: [PORTAL DAS COMUNIDADES PORTUGUESAS](https://portaldascomunidades.mne.gov.pt/pt/vai-viajar/conselhos-aos-viajantes/america/brasil), [ANA](https://www.ana.pt/pt/lis/guia-do-passageiro/o-que-preciso-de-saber/covid-19)

Comment: Good information

Comment: I have some relatives that traveled to Brazil 15 days ago. In the end, the PCR test was asked only in Portugal before the departure (by the airline).

Comment: My relatives arrived yesterday in Portugal. They traveled to Portugal using a TRAg test. The test was checked only by the airline also.